# Angular2 and TypeScript shows error "cannot find name 'Map' in VS2013

Tags: visual-studio-2013, typescript, angular

I am trying to build a Angular2 application using TypeScript in Visual Studio. I followed the steps shown in "5 min Quickstart" in angular2 site.(https://angular.io/guide/quickstart). But I got the following error as shown in following picture
[image]

Can anyone Help me to fix the issue "Cannot find name 'Map'? thanks a advanced
the `package.json` file definition is as follows

```
{
  "name": "angular2-quickstart",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "tsc && concurrently \"npm run tsc:w\" \"npm run lite\" ",
    "lite": "lite-server",
    "postinstall": "typings install",
    "tsc": "tsc",
    "tsc:w": "tsc -w",
    "typings": "typings"
  },
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common":  "2.0.0-rc.2",
    "@angular/compiler":  "2.0.0-rc.2",
    "@angular/core":  "2.0.0-rc.2",
    "@angular/http":  "2.0.0-rc.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser":  "2.0.0-rc.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic":  "2.0.0-rc.2",
    "@angular/router":  "2.0.0-rc.2",
    "@angular/router-deprecated":  "2.0.0-rc.2",
    "@angular/upgrade":  "2.0.0-rc.2",
    "systemjs": "0.19.27",
    "core-js": "^2.4.0",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.3",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.6",
    "zone.js": "^0.6.12",
    "angular2-in-memory-web-api": "0.0.12",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.6"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "concurrently": "^2.0.0",
    "lite-server": "^2.2.0",
    "typescript": "^1.8.10",
    "typings":"^1.0.4"
  }
}
```

Comment: Even I had a similar issue with Visual Studio 2015. But, my code compiled even though `map` is showing error in IDE. Try compiling using command prompt and use Visual Studio Code. That might help.

Comment: Have you included tsconfig.json? And does it have "sourceMap": true ?

Answer (score 3):

I had to change VS file as documented here **`typescriptServices.js`**

#### [Invalid module name in augmentation #8518](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/8518#issuecomment-217960231)

> I see the issue now. this is a duplicate of #7415, and should be fixed
>   in the next release (see #7507).
>
> As work arounds for now, you can replace `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TypeScript\typescriptServices.js`
>   with the file in
>   https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/Fix8518/lib/typescriptServices.js.
>   First take a local backup though.

This is related to VS 2015, but somewhere below should be also some solution for VS 2013

Comment: try to exclude the `node_modules` folder in your `tsconfig.json` file

Comment: I've been working on this problem all day. I tried (1) installing latest node 3.10.3 and npm 6.3.0 (2) installed latest typescript for Visual Studio 2015 - v1.8.6 (3) Installed latest update 3 of VS. Nothing helped. This finally got rid of the red squigglies.

Answer (score 0):

After googling a lot at last i found the solution and i want to share it with all of you
just add the following line at the top of component .ts file

```
///<reference path="../node_modules/angular2/typings/browser.d.ts"/>
```

just see the picture below

[image]

**Update**
if you use anguler2 beta(angular2/core) then you should add

```
///<reference path="../node_modules/angular2/typings/browser.d.ts"/>
```

but if you use angular2 rc1/rc2/rc3(@angular2/core) the you should add

```
/// <reference path="../node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.es6.d.ts" />
```

Answer (score 0):

To fix this issue you open your typings.d.ts and comment the below lines
Comment out the below code, it will fix your problem.

```
//declare var module: {
//  id: string;
//};
```